# Github:commit was merged to master but I am not in contributor list

Tags: github, pull-request

I have a GitHub commit to my own fork and I make a pull request to github. After several days, my commit was merged from my fork to master branch. But I cannot see my names in contributor list of this project. I don't know the difference. Can anyone could explain this to me？

[image]

Another question, what's the difference between contributors and members?